# searchbar filter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, list, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a javascript searchbar filter. I have these 5 footballclub names here and I want to make a searchbar so that if I type for example an "F" only the club : "Feyenoord" is visible.

HTML Code:

```
<form class="search-name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search club">
</form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
const $searchBar = document.querySelector(`.search-name`);
$searchBar.addEventListener(`keyup`, function(e){

  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const clublists = list.getElementsByClassName(`club-info`);
  Array.from(clublists).forEach(function(clublist){
  const clubname = clublist.firstElementChild.textContent;
  if(clubname.toLowerCase().includes(term) != -1){

    clublist.style.display = `block`;
  } else {
    clublist.style.display = `none`;

        }
    })
});
```

When I start to type in the searchbar, this is the error I get in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `list` is not defined
>       at HTMLFormElement. (scritp.js:39)

This is line 39:

```
 const $clublists = list.getElementsByClassName(`club-info`);
```

Comment: where do you define `list`?

Comment: @dgig I'm making a list from the all the elements of the class ".club-info" and I save that in the const clublists

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder. I didn't knew that. I won't do it in the future anymore. The problem is fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 39 to:

`const clublists = document.getElementsByClassName('club-info');`

You never define `list` anywhere - normally you'd have defined it and set it to be a collection with one of the `getElement(s)By...` methods. But in your case you're getting an error because you haven't done so. So you can just pull your list using the document as the base.

*also*

You need to add your `keyup` event listener to the actual text input, not to the form itself.

```
<form>
   <input class="search-name" type="text" placeholder="Search club">
</form>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maubh9z4/13/

Comment: Right - still playing. You have a few issues. You need to add your keyup event listener to the actual text input, not to the form itself.